# Problems building OpenCV code on linux

Tags: c++, linux, opencv

I have recently been trying to properly configure eclipse to be able to use OpenCV. After installing it to my computer, (Ubuntu, using cmake) I attempted to build some sample code from the OpenCV tutorials. 
This is the sample code.

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <highgui.h>

using namespace cv;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  Mat image;
  image = imread( argv[1], 1 );

  if( argc != 2 || !image.data )
    {
      printf( "No image data \n" );
      return -1;
    }

  namedWindow( "Display Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  imshow( "Display Image", image );

  waitKey(0);

  return 0;
}
```

Some additions to includes to make it work.

Everything is found properly, but when build, gives these 3 errors. (the file I am compiling is named test.cpp)

```
./test.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC    

make: *** [libOpenCV] Error 1   

recipe for target 'libOpenCV' failed
```

I dont know why these errors are happening, or how to fix it. Anyone have any clue?

Comment: Well, the error message tells you what to do - recompile your code with the `-fPIC` flag.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check the link obj, opencv requires number of libraries to work properly. Pls check the detail manual on opencv website.